# How can I insert a tooltip on points of victory scatter graph using a dataComponent

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

I'm trying to insert a tooltip on point of a Victory scatter plot where I use a dataComponent to modify the format of the dots, here is the code

```
    class CatPoint extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const {x, y, datum} = this.props;
        const cat = datum._y >= 0 ? "" : "";
        return (
          <text x={x} y={y} fontSize={30}>
            {cat}
          </text>
        );
      }
    }
    
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <VictoryChart>
            
            <VictoryScatter
              labelComponent={<VictoryTooltip flyoutStyle={{fill: "black"}}/>}
              data={[
                {x: 1, y: 3, label: "Alpha"},
                {x: 2, y: 4, label: "Bravo"},
                {x: 3, y: 6, label: "Charlie"},
                {x: 4, y: 3, label: "Delta"},
                {x: 5, y: 7, label: "Echo"},
              ]}
              dataComponent={<CatPoint/>}
            />
          </VictoryChart>
        );
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, mountNode);
```

I've tryed many things but was not able to do it.

I found the solution on this link

[https://spectrum.chat/victory/general/datacomponent-and-labelcomponent-on-the-same-chart-component~bc94b716-bb76-4bf9-86da-c87e1f38e370](https://spectrum.chat/victory/general/datacomponent-and-labelcomponent-on-the-same-chart-component%7Ebc94b716-bb76-4bf9-86da-c87e1f38e370)

Comment: Can you post the solution? The above link is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

import imgs and pass them like this:

```
import green from "./green.png"
import red from "./red.png"

class CatPoint extends Component {
      render() {
        const {x, y, datum} = this.props;
        const daticon = datum.y <= 0 ? green : red;
        return (
          <g>        
            <image {...this.props.events} x={x} y={y} 
                  width="20"
                  height="20"
                  href={daticon}                      
            <VictoryTooltip labelComponent={datum.label}/> 
          </g>
       )
      }
    }
```